# IntegerPart Removes A Number

Tags: list-manipulation, precision-and-accuracy

I have a list of numbers that goes like (Middle section omitted for length reasons):

```
{1., 2., 3., 4., 5., ... 16., 17., 18., 19., 20., 21.}
```

With the extra decimals because of how the list was created (something I can't avoid). I tried to use `IntegerPart` to get these without decimals, so they can be used as indices. For some reason, however, that causes the number 19 to disappear. The rest of the list is there, just as one would expect, but it looks like this:

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 20, 21}
```

Any thoughts? I just want to extract the integer parts of all of these numbers without discarding 19.

Comment: It cannot repreduce my case..

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem either.

Comment: Why don't you use Round?

Comment: try this:  `20. - 2*^-14  (*20.*) `  then  `IntegerPart[%] (*19*)`  Use `Round` instead

Comment: It is extremely unlikely that this is correctly reported. Please provide a simple example that produces your unwelcome output.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I cannot reproduce the problem the user is experiencing.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with

```
data = Range[21] // N
```

I tried

```
Round[data]
IntegerPart[data + .1]
Rationalize[data]
Floor[data + .1]
Ceiling[data - .1]
```

which are all the reasonable and semi-reasonable methods I could think of. All of them gave

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21}
> ```

as expected. I am at a loss to reproduce your problem.